# Android studio wont recognize key word "Builder"?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a circular action button and I have android 6.0, with a minimum api of 16 and a target of 23. I imported a dependency for the ciruclar aciton button but it wont recognize the key word Builder?

```
        FloatingActionButton actionButton=new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
 .setContentView(icon).build();
```

Dependecies are below

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
```

Comment: you need to import the right package for  FloatingActionButton.

Comment: compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2' is the right package

Answer (score 0):

Floating Action Button

You are trying with external dependicies for FAB, but you can get it easily from android design library, which is officially from Google.

require dependicies are

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

in xml,

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

and get it in java code,

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Click action
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewMessageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

For detail, go to AndroidHive's [post](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/)